# One-way ANOVA with a varying number of measurements per subject

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to run an ANOVA that accounts for multiple measurements within a subject and where the number of measurements differs across subjects. The factor (treatment) of interest is fixed within a subject across these multiple measurements.

I've read numerous examples about ANOVA using repeated measures but I can't convince myself that this is the right way to approach the problem, since these usually have data on the subjects across all factor levels. I only observe a subject in a single value of the (binary) treatment.

I'll explain the data structure and then give more explanation.  Here is the data:

```
# Sample Data
id  n  y  x   z
 0  1 29  1  34
 1  1 22  0  15
 1  2 30  0  16
 2  1 17  1  10
 2  2 19  1  10
 2  3 20  1  12
 3  1 24  0  17
 4  1 20  1  20
 5  1 22  0  24
 5  2 25  0  24
 5  3 21  0  29
 5  4 22  0  18

# Variable definitions
id - the subject ID
n  - the measurement attempt for that subject 
y  - the outcome of interest (continuous)
x  - factor of interest (binary, constant within a subject)
z  - a subject-specific factor that can vary across measurement attempts (continuous) 
     definitely impacts the outcome y
```

My goal: does **x** have an impact on **y**, controlling for **z** and accounting for the fact that each subject has a varying number of observations (defined by the pair **id,n**)?

Another researcher involved insists on running an ANOVA because "a regression is only meant for continuous predictors and continuous predicted variables." In a regression setting (and using something like Stata syntax), I keep wanting to run a regression such as:

```
 # regress and cluster standard errors by subject
 regress y x z x*z, vce(cluster id)

 # test joint hypothesis on x and the interaction x*z
 test x x*z
```

Alternatively, maybe some type of random effects model using 'xtreg' or 'mixed'?

However, the other researcher is more senior than I am and they insist on an ANOVA of some sort, even though I understand that a regression underlies an ANOVA. I'm looking for the right solution in either Stata (preferred) or R. I tried using the regular anova package, the wsanova library, and read various online forums but I'm not certain.  This seems like it should be a simple problem, so I'm hoping someone on here can point me in the right direction.

Many thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: if you are interested in multiple regression, state your model first.